# How to tell if object is in NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray

Is there a way to tell if a certain object is in an NSArray? The way I am adding objects to my array makes it possible for the same object to be added multiple times and I wanted to see if there was a way to see if it was already there (anywhere) in that array.

Comment: Apple Documentation is really well written.  On simple questions like this it is always best to just take a look at the related documentation (In this case NSArray) and you can usually get your answer in 2 min or less.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The NSArray `containsObject:` method is precisely for this purpose, its full signature being:

```
- (BOOL)containsObject:(id)anObject
```

See the full [NSArray Class Reference docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) for more information.

Answer (score 11):

```
if([yourArray indexOfObject:yourObject] == NSNotFound) {
     // your object is not in here
}
```

**Edit**: middaparkas approach is way better (if you don't want the index …)!

Comment: Thank you, this may be particularly useful later and it answers my question.